# How do I offset data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that i needs column y data to be offset by n number of dates later. For example on the screenshot below, reference date for 22nd April should be offset by data in columns X 3 days later.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please do not share data as image but in *text* format. Like this, every readers could easily copy/past it. Also, be sure to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding the current input and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want shift each 3 days:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%b')
df['Y'] = df['X'].shift(-3, freq='d')
```

If want shift each 3 rows:

```
df['Y'] = df['X'].shift(-3)
```